# Overlap area of 2 ellipses using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, ellipse

Does anyone know if it is possible to calculate the overlapping area of two ellipses using `matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`.

I have to ellipses like this:

[image]

And i would like to calculate the ratio between the overlap area and the are of the individual ellipses.
Is this possible using only the `Ellipse` from `matplotlib.patches`

Comment: Matplotlib is a plotting library, it does not calculate geometric identities.   But because you define the ellipses yourself you can calculate the area of overlap from the parameters you plug into the ellipse's definition `xy, width, height, angle`.

Comment: If you google for area of intersection between two ellipses, you will find that this is not a simple problem at all if you want to do it analytically. See for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1688449) for some outline how to do it. Therefore, a numerical approximation might well be appropriate. Still, matplotlib is not the tool for the job, so I would suggest to reconsider the tags to the question. matplotlib might still be relevant for visualisation, though.

Comment: Those ellipses look pretty circular. There is a simple formula to compute the common area of two circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot compute the area of the intersect with `matplotlib` (at least not to my knowledge), but you can use `shapely` to do so and then use `matplotlib` to *visualise* the result. Here a quick demo:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry.point import Point
from shapely import affinity
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

def create_ellipse(center, lengths, angle=0):
    """
    create a shapely ellipse. adapted from
    https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243462
    """
    circ = Point(center).buffer(1)
    ell = affinity.scale(circ, int(lengths[0]), int(lengths[1]))
    ellr = affinity.rotate(ell, angle)
    return ellr

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

##these next few lines are pretty important because
##otherwise your ellipses might only be displayed partly
##or may be distorted
ax.set_xlim([-5,5])
ax.set_ylim([-5,5])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

##first ellipse in blue
ellipse1 = create_ellipse((0,0),(2,4),10)
verts1 = np.array(ellipse1.exterior.coords.xy)
patch1 = Polygon(verts1.T, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch1)

##second ellipse in red    
ellipse2 = create_ellipse((1,-1),(3,2),50)
verts2 = np.array(ellipse2.exterior.coords.xy)
patch2 = Polygon(verts2.T,color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch2)

##the intersect will be outlined in black
intersect = ellipse1.intersection(ellipse2)
verts3 = np.array(intersect.exterior.coords.xy)
patch3 = Polygon(verts3.T, facecolor = 'none', edgecolor = 'black')
ax.add_patch(patch3)

##compute areas and ratios 
print('area of ellipse 1:',ellipse1.area)
print('area of ellipse 2:',ellipse2.area)
print('area of intersect:',intersect.area)
print('intersect/ellipse1:', intersect.area/ellipse1.area)
print('intersect/ellipse2:', intersect.area/ellipse2.area)


plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: result of above code]

And the computed areas (printed out to the terminal) are:

```
area of ellipse 1: 25.09238792436751
area of ellipse 2: 18.81929094327563
area of intersect: 13.656608779925698
intersect/ellipse1: 0.5442530547945023
intersect/ellipse2: 0.7256707397260032
```

Note that I adapted the code to generate the ellipse-shaped polygon from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243462). Hope this helps.