# Ellipse Overlap Area

Tags: geometry, overlap, ellipse

I am working on an *Eye Tracking* application, and when I detect the pupil and enveloping it with an ellipse I have to compare it to a ground-truth (exact ellipse around the pupil).

There are always 3 cases of course:

1. No Overlap >> overlap = intersection = 0
2. Partial to Perfect Overlap >> overlap = intersection area / ground-truth area
3. Enclosing >> overlap = intersection area / ground truth

My problem is the 3rd case where e.g. found ellipse is much bigger than the ground-truth hence enclosing it inside so the total overlap is given as 1.0 which is mathematically right but detection-wise not really as the found ellipse doesn't only contain the pupil inside it but other non-pupil parts.

**The question is:**
What would be the best approach to measure and calculate the overlap percentage between the found and ground-truth ellipses? would be just mere division of the areas?

Please give some insights.

*P.S.: I am coding with python and tried to use `shapely` library for the task as mentioned in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808941/overlap-area-of-2-ellipses-using-matplotlib) as supposedly it does the transform to position the ellipses correctly regarding their rotational angle.*

Comment: Given that the area of an ellipse is `A= a·b·pi`, it means that two different ellipses can have the same area. So, comparing areas is not the way to go.

Comment: If you are able to get the mathematic data `a,b` (semiaxes) for each ellipse, you could scale one so a semiaxis is the same in both ellipses and compare the other semiaxis of both ellipses. Or rotate the scaled ellipse so both axes-system fit and find intersection by pixel-to-pixel comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `R` be the reference ellipse, `E` the calculated ellipse.

We define `score := area(E ∩ R) / area(E ∪ R)`. The larger the score the better the match.

As `∅ ⊆ E ∩ R ⊆ E ∪ R`, we have `0 ≤ score ≤ 1`, `score=0 ⇔ (E ∩ R = ∅)` and
`score=1 ⇔ E=R`.

Consider an ellipse that is completely enclosed by `R` and has half the area, as well as an ellipse that completely encloses `R` and has twice the area. Both would have a score of 0.5 . If they were closer to `R`, for example if the first had 4/5 the area and the second 5/4 the area both would have a score of 0.8 .